# Should I always avoid lower case class names?

Tags: coding-style, dart

The following is incompatible with the [Dart Style Guide](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/).  Should I not do this?  I'm extending the `num` class to build a unit of measure library for medical applications.  Using lower case looks more elegant than Kg or Lbs.  In some cases using lower case is recommended for safety i.e. mL instead of Ml.

```dart
class kg extends num {
    String uom = "kg";
    num _value;

    lbs toLbs() => new lbs(2.20462 * _value);
}

class lbs extends num {
    String uom = "lbs";
    num _value;

    kg toKg() => new kg(_value/2.20462);
}
```

Comment: this link may help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java

Comment: Interesting idea. I wouldn't have thought extending num is possible because int and double cant't be extended.

Comment: For what it's worth, [API docs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-core.num) forbid extending `num`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you if you use them.
There might be situations where it can be important.
One I can think of currently is when you have an open source project and you don't want to alienate potential contributors.

When you have no special reason stick with the guidelines, if you have a good reason deviate from it.

Comment: I'm overwhelmed how helpful everyone has been.  I feel that I'm going to go down this path for a patient safety reason that many medical applications fail.  Sometimes we don't know until we build the full picture.  I'll build this and throw it out into the Dart community and see what everyone thinks.  Thank you again for being so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For your case I might pick a unit (e.g. milligrams) and make other units multiples of it. You can use division for conversion:

```dart
const mg = 1; // The unit
const g = mg * 1000;
const kg = g * 1000;
const lb = mg * 453592;


main() {
  const numPoundsPerKilogram = kg / lb;
  print(numPoundsPerKilogram); // 2.20462...

  const twoPounds = lb * 2;
  const numGramsInTwoPounds = twoPounds / g;
  print(numGramsInTwoPounds); // 907.184
}
```

It's best to make the unit small, so other units can be integer multiples of it (`int`s are arbitrary precision).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use classes for units. Use them for quantities:

```dart
class Weight {
  static const double LBS_PER_KG = 2.20462;

  num _kg;
  Weight.fromKg(this._kg);
  Weight.fromLbs(lbs) {
    this._kg = lbs / LBS_PER_KG;
  }

  get inKg => _kg;
  get inLbs => LBS_PER_KG * _kg;
}
```

take a look at the Duration class for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Coding conventions serve to help you write quality, readable code. If you find that ignoring a certain convention helps to improve the readability, that is your decision.

However, code is rarely only seen by one pair of eyes. Other programmers will be confused when reading your code if it doesn't follow the style guide. Following coding conventions allows others to quickly dive into your code and easily understand what is going on. Of course, it is possible that you really will be the only one to ever view this code, in which case this is moot.

I would avoid deviating from the style guide in most cases, except where the advantage is very obvious. For your situation I don't the advantage outweighs the disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really take those coding standards too seriously.

I think these guidelines are much more reasonable: less arbitrary, and more useful:

- Java: [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)
- Javascript: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

There are many more you can choose from - pick whatever works best for you!

PS:

As long as you're talking about Dart, check out this article:

- [Google Dart to ultimately replace Javascript](http://css.dzone.com/news/google-dart-%E2%80%9Cultimately) ... not!

Comment: You can't just pick another language's coding conventions. You're missing one of the huge advantages of coding conventions; other programmers are able to read your code easily.